# InetAddress throws hostname can't be null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket

is there any way to override the constructor of `InetSocketAddress` ? our current IP doesnt have a hostname and when i try to connect my websocket to our server it throws `hostname can't be null` due to

```
@Override
    public InetSocketAddress getLocalAddress() {
        return new InetSocketAddress(this.servletRequest.getLocalName(), this.servletRequest.getLocalPort());
    }
```

in ServletServerHttpRequest.class. or can i modify my inetaddress through web.xml or filter?

Comment: No you can't; fix your code instead.

Comment: the only way is to track all the connected class that uses the `request`?

Comment: Why not use your current IP as the hostname?

Comment: No, it isn't the only way. You can check whether `getLocalName()` returns null, and if so use "localhost". Or fix your DNS.

Comment: the problem is the websocket framework calls the `getLocalName()` and the request comes from the container. i've found that request from tomcat uses this class [Request Facade](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/RequestFacade.html)

Comment: The problem here is really your broken DNS. Fix it.